# Trying a data frame to an sf object, function used: st_as_sf()

Tags: r, geometry, coordinates, geospatial, r-sf

I am trying to execute following code as .R file in Azure batch service:

**Data <- st_as_sf(data, coords = c("Longitude", "Latitude")) %>% sf::st_set_crs(4326)**

and I am getting following error:
**Error in `[.data.frame`(x, coords) : undefined columns selected
Calls: %>% ... st_as_sf.data.frame -> as.data.frame -> lapply -> [ -> [.data.frame
Execution halted**

Any kind of help would be appreciated

Comment: what does `names(data)` give you?

Comment: It give me names of all columns as following:
[1] "X...ColumnA"                  
 [2] "ColumnB"                     
 [3] "ColumnC"          
 [4] "Latitude"                             
 [5] "Longitude"

Comment: This is a WAG, but perhaps, rather than `_sf(data`, you `dput(data))`, copy the `structure(....)` of your data, and make your R script call `Data_sf <- st_as_sf(x = structure(....), coords = `, so that our 'data' is actually in the Azure processing environment, far far away. 'data' in your local environment is readily found, data out there probably needs to be provided, and there are likely other mechanisms than this one suggested, ie. someone who knows/uses Azure will wander along. Welcome to Stackoverflow.

Comment: And probably put Azure in your title to interest that particular expert.